# Using the URL file preview from Details pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, url

I'm trying to make a document library containing PDF files and URL files, to show previews/thumbnails for all of the files.

PDFs are easy as it's built in but I'm trying to find any possible way to have the same thing for the URLs.

I found that the details pane on the URL files actually has a built in function that does in fact give the preview/thumbnail of the linked PDF file. I want to use this function directly in the page or on the URL file.

How would I achieve this? Can I hook into the getpreview.ashx that seems to be the element getting them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not available in the details panel, if the linked file points to a site, there is no thumbnail you mentioned in this panel:

[image]

Therefore,**Link** file format is not suppoted by thumbnail, we cannot see thumbnails for all of the files.